# Getting Chart.js to work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, charts

I am going through Chart.js and would like to check how to enable it on IE through the use of excanvas.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#generalIssues-browserSupport). The code work nicely on modern browser with html5 support.

However, I can't seem to get it work. Can anyone point to me where I did it wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script src="site/assets/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var data = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                },
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
                }
            ]
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(ctx).Line(data,{});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any luck with this? i have similar problem ,my ie console says 'data.datasets[...].data' is null

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem , if have pls share.Qn:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817843/chart-is-not-showing-with-excanvas-in-ie8-mode`

Answer (score 0):

After create your ctx var, you need to put the following line :

"G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(ctx);"

This declaration uses the excanvas.js lib to initialize you canvas object.